# using csv module to import text files

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use the csv module to import two files neatly. The first one (books.txt) seems to be importing neatly into a list fine. The second bit requires it to be inserted into a dict. I've tried various solutions I've found online but can't get it to work as desired. It should loop through the text file, line1 should be the key, line2 the value, line3 the second key, and so on

```
import csv

def importer():
    with open('books.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
        reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
        books = list((row) for row in reader)
    print(books)

    with open('ratings.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
        reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
        ratings = list((row) for row in reader)
    print(ratings)


importer()
```

The source .txt files and full code is visible here

https://repl.it/@glasgowm1498/CoralTangibleWamp

My previous code before rewriting was as follows:

```
ratings = {}
with open('ratings.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        name = f.readline().strip()
        values = f.readline().strip().split()
        if not name:
            break
        else:
            ratings[name] = list(int(i) for i in values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
import csv

rateDict = {}
with open('ratings.txt', newline='') as inputfile:
    reader = csv.reader(inputfile)
    ratings = list((row) for row in reader)

keys = [x[0] for x in ratings[::2] if x]       # doublecheck input if every even row is key
data = [x[0].split() for x in ratings[1::2]]   # doublecheck input if every odd row is data


# rateDict = dict( zip(keys,data))   # shortcut if you do need no postprocc

for k,d in zip(keys,data):  # marry key to data
    # do something with d, f.e. 
    # d = list(map(int,d))
    rateDict[k]=d               # store in dict

for k in rateDict.items() :
    print(k)
```

Output (cropped):

```
('Ben', ['5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '-3', '5', '0',
         '0', '0', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0',
         '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '-5', '0', '0', '5',
         '5', '0', '5', '5', '5', '0', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5',
         '5', '5', '-5'])
('Moose', ['5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '1', '0', '5', '3',
           '0', '5', '0', '3', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', 
           '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '-3',
           '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '0',
           '3', '0', '0'])
('Reuven', ['5', '-5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-3', '-5', '0', '1', '-5', '5',
            '0', '1', '0', '1', '-3', '1', '-5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 
            '0', '3',  ... etc ... ]
```